# How to change level access after submitting a form?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem to make a web application where I could input a data of a customer, where user level-1 could input data and then user level-2 could check the data, and then user level-3 could approve the data and save it to database. So in every page I want to keep login with different username and password. So every level user would have their own username and password. And how can I make the application where the data that has been inputted by user level-1 in computer-1 to go to user level-2 in computer-2 for checking without saving the data to database and to user level-3 for approval in computer-3 where they would save the data ?
I'm using php and mysql. Could someone maybe give me a help? please.

Comment: Save data to mysql but use statuses - added, checked, approved. On site you will show only data with `approved` status

Answer (score 0):

you could have a second database for unapproved/unchecked data but that would not be the ideal way to do it, you would be better to do as u_mulder suggested and save to the database and have a separate column in the database table to show the status of the data